# Correspondence between Parabolic groups and highest Weights for complex algebraic groups

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a simple algebraic group over
$\mathbb{C}$ and $ T  \subset G$ the Cartan
sub-Lie-group (ie the maximal torus) and $\text{Hom}(T, \mathbb{C}^*)$ it's dual space. The lattice of weights
$\Lambda_W \subset \text{Hom}(T, \mathbb{C}^*)$
is the set of $\beta \in \text{Hom}(T, \mathbb{C}^*)$
such that $\beta(H_{\alpha}) \in \mathbb{Z}$
for all co-roots $H_{\alpha}$ of the simple roots $\alpha$.

There is a known way to relate highest weights
$\lambda \in \Lambda_W$ of $G$ living in a distinguished/fixed
Weyl chamber (which in turn correspond to isomorphism
classes of irreducible representations $V= \Gamma_{\lambda}$)
to parabolic subgroups $P_{\lambda}$. The explicit way
to do it can be found, eg in Fulton & Harris'
Representation Theory (p. 388) as follows:

The irreducible representation $V= \Gamma_{\lambda}$ of $G$
induces an action of $G$ on the projective space
$\mathbb{P}V$, the projectivisation of $V$. Let
$p \in \mathbb{P}V$ be the point corresponding to the
eigenspace with eigenvalue $\lambda$; that's welldefined
since the eigenspace is one-dimensional.
The point $p$ is fixed under the Borel subgroup $B$
(which is iniquely determined after fixing the
positive roots in the corresponding Lie-algebra
representation), and the associated parapolic space
$P_{\lambda}$ is the the stabilizer
of $p$; the orbit $G/P_{\lambda} = G \cdot p$ is
compact and hence closed.

**Simple question:** Why under this construction
the orbit $G \cdot p$ is *not* always the complete
space $\mathbb{P}V$? Following considerations lead me to the conclusion that the orbit should be the whole space $\mathbb{P}V$ or equivalently that $G$ act transitively on $\mathbb{P}V$. What I'm doing wrong in my considerations below?

Let $V= \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A_{\lambda}} V_{\alpha}$ the weight decomposition of $V$ with respect the weights $\alpha: T \to \mathbb{C}^*$ of the representation $V$ for Cartan group $\text{exp}(\mathfrak{t})=T  \subset G$. Since $V$ is associated with highest weight $\lambda$, every $\alpha$ with $V_{\alpha} \neq 0$ equals $\lambda$ modulo the space of roots $\Lambda_{Ad}$, ie the weights of the adjoint representation $\text{Ad}: G \to \mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$.
These decompose $\mathfrak{g}$ into $\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{r} \in \Lambda_{Ad}} \mathfrak{g}_{\mathfrak{r}}$.

Therefore if $\alpha= \lambda + \mathfrak{r}$, $\mathfrak{r}$ root $G$ with eigenspace $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathfrak{r}} \subset \mathfrak{g}$, then for any nonzero $v \in \mathfrak{g}_{\mathfrak{r}}$, we have $V_{\alpha} = \text{exp}(v)(V_{\lambda})$ and therefore $G \cdot V_{\lambda}$ hits every direct summand $V_{\alpha}$ in the weight decomposition $V= \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A_{\lambda}} V_{\alpha}$. Therefore it hits every one-dimensional subspace in $V$, since the representation is linear. But then the action by $G$ would be transitive on $\mathbb{P}V$ and the orbit $G \cdot p$ would be the complete space $\mathbb{P}V$, or not?

But in the book is stated that in general $G/P_{\lambda} = G \cdot p$ is only a closed subspace of $\mathbb{P}V$. What is my error in the considerations above?

Comment: Just work out the irreducible representation of $SL(2)$ into $SL(3)$ and you find your mistake.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: just to clarify: what do you mean by "irreducible representation of $SL(2)$ into $SL(3)$"? 
A guess: the irreps a classifies by integers, ie up to iso 
for every $n$ there exist exactly one irrep on
$V_n = \mathbb{C}^n$. So do you just mean by 
"irrep of $SL(2)$ into $SL(3)$" the unique irrep of 
$SL(2)$ on
$\mathbb{C}^3$?

Comment: Of course. It is also known as the adjoint representation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: In this case the maximal torus is generated by single element, the exponent of $H$ (where I used notions for $H$ from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2)#Real_and_complexified_Lie_algebras), and therefore roots are just numbers and not functionals on $H$. We obtain the decomposition $V= V_{-2} \oplus V_0 \oplus V_2$ with highest weight $2$ and eg $X \in V_2$ an eigenvector, ie $V_2=\langle X \rangle$. Then $exp(Y)V_2= V_0$ and $exp(Y)V_0= V_{-2}$.

Comment: And therefore for the eigenspace decomposition of $V$ above $G \cdot V_2$ "covers" the whole space $V$, and so the orbit of the "line" $V_2$ should hit by $G$ any other line of $V$, in other words $G$ act transitively on $\mathbb{P}V$, or not? I not see where my argument breaks down

Comment: What you wrote "and so the orbit of the "line" 2 should hit by  any other line of " is totally unjustified (does not follow from the eigenvalue decomposition) and simply wrong. Indeed, $V$ is just the Lie algebra of $G$, $V_2$ is spanned by a nonzero nilpotent 2-by-2 matrix, whose $G$-orbit in the projectivization of $V$ is a conic in $PV$ consisting of all nonzero nilpotent matrices. Obviously, this is not the entire projective space.

Comment: @JustusC "[...] we have $V_\alpha = \exp( v ) V_\lambda$," is not correct, as Moishe points out. Take $v=Y=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$, and suppose $V= V_{-1}\oplus V_1$. Then $$\pmatrix{1 & 0\\1 & 1}\pmatrix {t\\0}= \pmatrix{t \\t},$$ and not $$\pmatrix{0\\ t},$$ as your assertion would have one believe. (A clearer calculation would have been $$\pmatrix{1 & 0\\t& 1}\pmatrix {1\\0}= \pmatrix{1 \\t},$$ as taking the derivative gives the expected lie alg. assertion.)

Comment: oh yes, I see, not $ exp(Y)$ maps $ V_{\lambda}$ to $ V_{\alpha}$, but $ Y $ inself on level of  adjoint action of Lie algeba on itself.

Comment: @JustusC and fwiw surjectivity also fails in general for dimensional reasons. For instance, in Moishe's example, $G/B \simeq \mathbb P_1$ (1 dim'l cx proj space), whereas $\mathbb P(V) \simeq \mathbb P_2$.

Comment: @JustusC yes for $Y\in\mathfrak{g}^\alpha$ with $\alpha$ a root, we have $Y\cdot V_\lambda \subset V_{\lambda+\alpha}$ but the equivalent result for $\exp(Y)$ is $\exp(Y)\cdot V_\lambda \subset V_\lambda\oplus V_{\lambda+\alpha} \oplus V_{\lambda+2\alpha} \oplus \cdots$. This follows straightforwardly from the power series expansion of $\exp$ in the representation.

Comment: Another natural example here is the projective quadric. Let $Q$ be a quadratic form on $V$ and consider $\operatorname{SO}(V,Q)$ acting on $V$ as the transformations preserving $Q$. Then the highest weight vector will be null for $Q$ and since the group preserves $Q$ the orbit must always consist of null lines so definitely cannot be the whole space.

Comment: let me try to rephrase the origins of my confusion. I think that there are two, and the point seems to be that these are of completely different nature. The first one, we have only the relations $Y \cdot V_\lambda \subset V_{\lambda+\alpha} $ and $ \exp(Y)\cdot V_\lambda \subset V_\lambda\oplus V_{\lambda+\alpha} \oplus V_{\lambda+2\alpha} \oplus \cdots $. That's a specific fact for the theory of Lie groups & algebras.

Comment: But I have the feeling that Moishe Kohan meant another different important point, which has not to do with adjoint representation, but holds more generally: Assume a group $ G $ acts on a vector space $ V $ which is we assume to be given as a decomposition into $ \bigoplus_{a \in A} V_a $ where the $V_a$ one-dimensional subspaces. And we naively ASSUME that moreover $ G $ acts transitively on the the $V_a$ in the sense that for every pair $a,b /in A$ there exist a $ g /in G $ with $ g \cdot V_a = V_b$. Then EVEN UNDER THIS ASSUMPTION it's in general wrong that $G \cdot V_a= V $,

Comment: morally because the multiplicativity in $ G$ is in general unrelated to additivity of vector space $ V $ regarded as additive group. So the point seems to be that in much wrong conclusion I muddled up two strucures (multiplication law in $ G$ and additivity in $ V$) which essentially " not see each other." So EVEN IF we assume $G \cdot v_a$ for $v_a \in V_a $ hits all generators of the other factors $V_b$, then there is no reason that $G \cdot V_a$ cover whole $ V $ simply because $G$ not sees the addition V onder which it decomposes $ \bigoplus_{a \in A} V_a $ .

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: was this exactly the point of your concern in your previous comment? (besides of the wrong $ Y\cdot V_\lambda \subset V_{\lambda+\alpha} $ which Callum and Peter pointed out)?

Comment: What do you mean by "this" and by "concern"? (As far as I am concerned, I did not express any "concerns.") My point  was quite clear: I explained why $SL(2,C)$ does not act transitively on the projectivization of its Lie algebra $sl(2,C)$, giving you an explicit counter-example to your unjustified transitivity claim. What else would you like to know?

Comment: You wrote in the comment I'm refering to that the claim that the orbit $ G \cdot V_2 $ covers whole V is unjustified and cannot be deduced from eigenspace decomposition of V. and indeed that simply wrong as your conterexample shows. and in the last comments I tried to elaborate where essentially "the devil sits" such that the claim fails. Of course your example shows that the claim is wrong, but I was curiuos where my wrong intuition breaks down. and as I remarked it sems that it has to do with a kind of "defect" that the set of $ G \cdot V_2 $, ie the union of images of $V_2$ under elements

Comment: of $ G$ is a proper subset of it's linear closure inside $V$, which would under assumptions in my last comments the whole $ V $. So  essentially the failure that comes from  that the set $ G \cdot V_2$ is not a vector space. I just wanted to emphasise it, but nevermind :)

Comment: @JustusC at this point, maybe put an answer and accept it to take the question off the unanswered queue. It was a worthwhile and 'illuminating' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed a general fact that under the setting in the question,
$G$ in general not acts transitively on $\mathbb{P}V$, where
$V= V_{\lambda}$ is the irreducible rep of $G$ with maximal
weight $\lambda$. Here Moishe Kohan's counterexample:

Consider the adjoint rep of $SL_3(\mathbb{C})$. Since
the Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ is $3$-dimensional
and all irreps of $SL_3(\mathbb{C})$ are parametrized
by dimension, we have that the irrep $V:=\mathfrak{sl}_3$
decomposes in $V= V_{-2} \oplus V_0 \oplus V_2$ with
highest weight $2$. Let $p := [v_2] \in \mathbb{P}V \cong
\mathbb{P}^2$ where $v_2$ eigenvector of generating weight $2$.

Then $B= \text{Stab}(p)$ and $G/B \cong \mathbb{P}^1$, so
the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{P}V$ cannot be transitive.

Potential source for confusion: Let $V$ a vector space
with decomposition $V= \bigoplus_{a \in A} V_a$ in
*one-dimensional* vector spaces $V_a$.
Let $G$ a group acting linearly (ie there is a group homom
$G \to GL(V)$) on $V$ with additional
property that it acts transitively on the $V_a$'s: i.e.
for any pair of $a, b \in A$ there exist a $g \in G$ with
$g \cdot V_a =V_b$, then it not implies that
$G \cdot V_a=V$. Morally, that's because the $G \cdot V_a$
is not a subvector space on $V$.

In contrast, if there ie a Lie-algebra
$\mathfrak{g}$ which acts linearly on $V$
(ie there is a algebra homom $\mathfrak{g} \to End(V)$)
and as before  $\mathfrak{g}$ acts transitively
on the eigenspaces $V_a$, this implies in contrast to the
case of Lie group action that indeed
$V= \mathfrak{g} \cdot V_a$.

Important remark pointed out by Callum: The 'Potential source for confusion'-part is **not** exactly what happens in the setting above, since neither $\mathfrak{g}$ nor $G$ really act on the "set" of eigenspaces $ \{\{V_a \}, a\in I \} $, but it is indirectly related to this in the way
that even if all weight spaces $V_{\beta}$ are contained in the same $G$-orbit - where we consider the $G$-action on the set of all lines of $V$ -  this doesn't imply that the $G$-orbit of a picked $V_{\alpha}$ is the whole $V$, but on the other hand the orbit $\mathfrak{g} \cdot V_{\alpha}$ is the whole $V$ if the difference between any two weights is a root.

Comment: Sort of. You shouldn't really call that $G$ or $\mathfrak{g}$ acting "transitively" on the $V_a$ since $g\cdot V_a$ or $X\cdot V_a$ does not have to be another $V_b$. Instead what you should say to the same effect is that all weight spaces being in the same $G$-orbit doesn't imply that the orbit is the whole $\mathbb{P}V$ but that $\mathfrak{g}$ can generate the whole representation in one step from any weight space if the difference between any two weights is a root. Note these are actually fairly strict conditions to place on representations. The adjoint representation will always fail both.

Comment: yes thanks, $ X \cdot V_a= V_b$ is only true if $ X \in \mathfrak{g}_{b-a}$. I'll rectify it next days